# ENOENT: no such file or directory on compile and deploy swanky contract

Tags: polkadot-js, ink, astar

This issue display when I clone the swanky project from GH and try to compile.

`swanky contract compile {project_name}`

[image]

I try to ignore the issue which display while compiling and try to deploy and got this issue.

`swanky contract deploy {project_name} --account alice --gas 100000000000 --network shibuya`

[image]

> **swanky node running in the background**

Any suggestion how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please check if the .contract file exists in the following directory. "contracts/todo_list/target/ink". If it doesn't exist, please tell us the result of executing the compile command with "-v".

Comment: Which swnky-cli version are you using? There was an issue with copying artifacts some older versions. (latest one being 1.0.11)
Also, the swanky dev container is available now, it has a full environment set up with latest swanky version, and removes that warning from polkadot/util
https://github.com/AstarNetwork/swanky-dev-container

Comment: @s.Takahashi contract doesn't compile so no .contract file exists and result of executing compile command is 1st image

Comment: @codespool I am using `@astar-network/swanky-cli/1.0.10 darwin-x64 node-v18.2.0` I use [this precompiled binaries](https://docs.astar.network/docs/build/wasm/swanky#recommended-method-download-the-precompiled-binaries)

Comment: can you try https://github.com/AstarNetwork/swanky-cli/releases/tag/v1.0.11

Comment: @Ganesh11 Did it work with the latest release?

Answer (score 1):

There have been multiple new releases of `swanky-cli` since you posted: https://github.com/AstarNetwork/swanky-cli/releases.

There were some fixes for handling contract artifacts and it's likely that your issue will be resolved by using a recent `swanky-cli` version.